# Prevent player from "flying"

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, game-physics

I am currently trying to make an endless runner game, and I've just finished making the jumping mechanics. However, if the player were to hold the up arrow key, or press it before they touched the ground, they are able to mimic the ability to "fly". I am not sure how to prevent them from "flying" if they have not touched the ground yet. If anyone has any ideas, please let me know. My code is below:

```js
let ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

// Screen
ctx.canvas.height = 512;
ctx.canvas.width = 512;

// Images
let bg = new Image;
bg.src = "./Background.png";

let fl = new Image;
fl.src = "./Floor.png";

// Player
let y = 256;
let speed = 2.5;

let pl = new Image;
pl.src = "./Idle.png";
pl.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(pl, 0, y);
};

// Jumping
let UP = false;

// Ducking
let DOWN = false;

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 38) UP = true;
  if (e.keyCode == 40) DOWN = true;
};

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 38) UP = false;
  if (e.keyCode == 40) DOWN = false;
};

// Frames
function update() {

  // Clear
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 512, 512);

  // Background
  ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0);

  // Floor
  ctx.drawImage(fl, 0, 384);
  ctx.drawImage(fl, 128, 384);
  ctx.drawImage(fl, 256, 384);
  ctx.drawImage(fl, 384, 384);

  // UP
  if (UP) {
    if (y > 100) {
      ctx.drawImage(pl, 0, y -= speed);
    } else {
      UP = false;
    };
  } else if (!UP) {
    if (y < 256) {
      ctx.drawImage(pl, 0, y += speed);
    } else {
      ctx.drawImage(pl, 0, y);
    };
  };

  // DOWN
  if (DOWN) {
    pl.src = "./Duck.png";
  } else if (!DOWN) {
    pl.src = "./Idle.png";
  };
};

setInterval(update, 10);
```

Comment: You could create a trace underneath the player and only allow the player to jump if it's touching a solid object. Then, slap on a cooldown on the jump ability and it should be mostly fine.

Also, instead of tracing from the player downwards, i.e. vertically, creating a single horizontal trace underneath the player can be easier and better.

Comment: Add a variable `heightJumped` to check how high a player has jumped (add to it while the key is pressed). Once the player jumps that certain height, set another variable `allowJump` to false. If `allowJump` is false, don't add to the y. Once the user hits the ground, set `allowJump` to true.

Comment: Fixed it! Thanks for the help Rojo!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the player is colliding (touching) the ground, perhaps through [pixeldata](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas), if it is equal to the pixel data of the floor, then `onGround = true;`, if this condition is true then you can set `allowJump = true`, and when pixeldata is not equal to the ground, such as when you have jumped, it will no longer allow you to jump.